# C# Public accessor doesn't work anymore

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, class

why this doesn't work anymore in my web control?
it just throws a yellow error without any information about the code line. but just at this page... other errors are visible on other pages, it's enabled in web.config.

strange is I don't know what I have changed but I think before a week that was running..
It seems a problem with:

```
 private int _value;
```

regards, thanks.

```
private int _value;

public int Value
{
    get
    {
        return _value;
    }

    set
    {
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this exactly your code. did you copy it out of your source file?

Comment: Make sure that your private variable is still being initialized.

Comment: I work with Kentico an asp.net CMS and it's a usercontrol of type CMS:WebPart... could it be that there are restrictions of a class...?

Answer (score 2):

Can't see what's wrong just from that snippet.

> strange is I don't know what I have
>   changed but I thinkg before a week
>   that was running

First stop is to look at the diff of changes in source control between now and when you last thought it was working.  You do *have* source control right?...

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your code.  I would try to "clean" your solution and try again.  "Clean" is available in the Build Menu.